# How to run a test suite inside the Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm working the [Finance](https://rubygems.org/gems/finance) gem, and I am having an issue where some of the code fails when run inside Ruby on Rails.

I would like to test for this by running the existing test suite inside the Rails environment, however, I'm not sure how to go about this.  I'm looking for something to the effect of

```
run_all_tests
inside_rails do
  run_all_tests_again
end
```

inside my `Rakefile`, or wherever is most appropriate.

I haven't been able to find much on Google; any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: The default setup with tests that you write in rails is that it includes the rails app. This way you can access the models, controllers, etc to actually test those entities. I think the real question you want to ask is how to get the finance gem working. Make a question asking that and be sure to include the stack trace and a good description of the issue.

Comment: You could look into shared_examples: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-examples That way you could have shared_examples that run in both the context of the gem and in the context of the spec/dummy Rails application (or the Rails environment that uses the gem).